# NuPeek Symbols doesn't download source in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, debug-symbols

We recently installed NuPeek for our NuGet repository and NuPeek as symbols server.

NuGet works (above) fine. It was set up within an hour.

The Symbols Server on the other hand is a different story. Packages are pushed to NuPeek (normal packages and symbol packages). I see on the server that both are picked up and placed in the correct folder (source files too, .cs in this case).

I have set up Visual Studio so it can find the correct symbols server. When I create a new project, install the package (that also has a symbols package), use the code from that package and try to debug it, the following happens:

1. In the cache folder the "package" is downloaded
2. The cache folder also has a src folder. Within a source folder which has a folder with the same name as the package -> version.
3. The version folder is empty
4. The folder *cache*/ *packagename*.pdb/*guid*/ *packagename*.pdb is present

Still, Visual Studio cannot find the correct CS file to show. After some digging in the NuPeek server folders I noticed the folder *symbolsPath* -> temp -> *PackageName* -> lib -> net45 is empty, while the symbols.nupkg clearly has sources (one cs-file to be excact).

I had this working before, but we switched servers (Azure website to Azure CloudService), but I'm 99% sure this is not the problem.

Am I missing something? Does anyone has any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone has any clue?

If anyone does then the author of the project, Jérémie Chassaing, would be the most likely candidate.  Don't hesitate to add an issue to the [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/thinkbeforecoding/nupeek/issues?status=new&status=open).  Not much there right now and he looks pretty responsive so worth your time.

Do run through the setup checklist first:

- Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols, add `http://myserver/NuPeek/symbols` to the Symbol file locations list.  Ensure that you have a valid Cache symbols directory selected
- Tools + Options, Debugging, General, tick the "Enable source server support" option
- Untick the "Enable Just My Code" option.
- Tick the "Print source server diagnostics" option.  Update your question with what you see in the Output window so we'll have a better shot at figuring out the real problem

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is an old question but as i found the solution today i'll post it here.

This is probably because you instaled NuPeek too deep in your website structure.
A bug in Nupeek requires that it is installed at the root level of your site (for ex: www.domain.com, and not www.domain.com/Nupeek/).

Else you can fix the bug in SymbolTools.cs, replace the SourceBaseUri getter code by this :

```
    private static string SourceBaseUri
    {
        get
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            var applicationUri = new Uri(new Uri(httpRequest.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Scheme | UriPartial.Authority)), Path.Combine(httpRequest.ApplicationPath, "source"));

            return applicationUri.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.